# XADC buffer samples

Tags: buffer, xilinx, vivado, adc

Trying to rad converted sine wave from XADC. What buffer should i add (fifo, dma,bram) and is it possible to import 1024 samples of the sine wave (~30 kHz,1V)? Software code below[[image]]([image: VIVADO PROJECT])

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "platform.h"
#include "xil_printf.h"
#include "xsysmon.h"
#include "xparameters.h"
#include "sleep.h"

#define SYSMON_DEVICE_ID  XPAR_SYSMON_0_DEVICE_ID
#define C_BASEADDR 0x43C00000 //0x43C0_0000
#define XSysMon_RawToVoltage1(AdcData) ((((float)(AdcData))* (1.0f))/65536.0f)              //XSysMon_RawToVoltage
static XSysMon SysMonInst;
static int SysMonFractionToInt(float FloatNum);

int main()
{


    u32 RawData;//,RawData1,RawData2,RawData3;
    float Data;
    int xStatus;
     int count = 0;
    XSysMon_Config *SysMonConfigPtr;
    XSysMon *SysMonInstPtr =&SysMonInst;

    init_platform();

    //Xil_Out32(C_BASEADDR + 0x300 , 0x3); // 0x3 unipolar, 0x403 bipolar (C_BASEADDR + 0x300 , 0x3)
    // Xil_Out32(C_BASEADDR + 0x304 , 0x3F0F);
   //   Xil_Out32(C_BASEADDR + 0x308 , 0x0400);
   //   Xil_Out32(C_BASEADDR + 0x320 , 0x0800);


    SysMonConfigPtr = XSysMon_LookupConfig(SYSMON_DEVICE_ID);


    xStatus = XSysMon_CfgInitialize(SysMonInstPtr, SysMonConfigPtr, SysMonConfigPtr->BaseAddress);


    while(1)
    {


        RawData = XSysMon_GetAdcData(SysMonInstPtr,XSM_CH_VPVN);
        //RawData1 = XSysMon_GetAdcData(SysMonInstPtr,C_BASEADDR);
        //RawData2 = XSysMon_GetAdcData(SysMonInstPtr,0x43C5020C);
        //RawData3 = XSysMon_GetAdcData(SysMonInstPtr,0x43C0020C);
        Data = XSysMon_RawToVoltage1(RawData);
        xil_printf("\r\n %0d,%03d \r",(int)(Data), SysMonFractionToInt(Data)); //, SysMonFractionToInt(Data)
        //xil_printf("data = %d\n\r", Data);
         count++;
    }


    cleanup_platform();
    return 0;
}


/****************************************************************************/
/*
*
* This function converts the fraction part of the given floating point number
* (after the decimal point)to an integer.
*
* @param    FloatNum is the floating point number.
*
* @return   Integer number to a precision of 3 digits.
*
* @note
* This function is used in the printing of floating point data to a STDIO device
* using the xil_printf function. The xil_printf is a very small foot-print
* printf function and does not support the printing of floating point numbers.
*
*****************************************************************************/

int SysMonFractionToInt(float FloatNum)
{
    float Data;
    Data = FloatNum;
    if(FloatNum <0){
        Data = -(FloatNum);

    }
    return ( ((int)((Data -(float)((int)Data)) *(1000))));
}
```

Trying to rad converted sine wave from XADC. What buffer should i add (fifo, dma,bram) and is it possible to import 1024 samples of the sine wave (~30 kHz,1V)? Software code below